# Failed to create D3D shaders - webGL GLSL

Tags: glsl, webgl

I've been checking out the cool animations on [GLSL Sandbox](http://glslsandbox.com) but one of the demo isn't running for me, [this one](http://glslsandbox.com/e#28490.0). The error isn't in compilation though, but at runtime - it says that it **Failed to create D3D shaders**. I looked into the sandbox source and I can see that it directly passes on the exception from WebGL, so it's not a problem with the website but with the code.

I walked through the code but it's rather long and I see no mention of D3D shaders. It looks much like the other demos which are working fine.

So...

1. What part of the code causes the problem? Could I comment something out to get it to work?
2. Is the problem browser dependent? Or does it depend on my OpenGL version?

Comment: The shader code, error message, and browser you're using would help. The error I get under Chrome is `C:\fakepath(527,34-214): error X3005: '_sky': identifier represents a variable, not a function`, which is admittedly strange because there is no variable named `_sky` anywhere.

Comment: Actually, I meant this as a general question, like: "What does this error mean?". And I don't think there's anything wrong with that. PS.: Link to the live code example **and** the error are contained in my question. Really, only information you need here is the answer.

Comment: SO requires that you put the code and the error message in the question itself, not as a link to another website (which is vulnerable to link rot). The error message in particular may vary across browsers, or even be browser specific.

Comment: Do I need to make a search query for first 1000 of questions about errors that do not contain code because they are about the error in general, or will you do the query yourself? Because you're really just being annoying on question you can't answer instead of answering many other questions that you can answer. I see no point in copying 500 lines of code here.That error means something and I want to know what and I'm sure someone who knows will come and answer instead of flaming in comments.

Comment: Considering that glslang accepts the shader without any warnings and Chrome mentions mangled-looking names (like `_webgl_136aa2988a66a964`) in the error logs, this looks like an implementation bug rather than a programming error in the shader. That makes it a very specific problem, that most people won't have "in general".

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo If you're so sure, why don't you just use the edit the question? This is what the edit feature is for. You know where the code is, and you know as much or more about it as I do. But no, you're the talker.

Comment: Quite certainly the error is caused by `ANGLE` breaking the shader when transpiling from GLSL to HLSL, you can check the transpiled source using [WEBGL_debug_shaders](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_debug_shaders/)